# I accidently deleted a few folders; can't seem to reinstall

Tags: postgresql

I accidentally deleted a few folders for postgresql. I tried `apt-get purge postgresql` and `apt-get install postgresql` and `apt-get install --reinstall postgresql`. When I write `find / -type d -name postgresql` it only finds `/usr/share/doc/postgresql`. There should be several directories. When I switch to user postgres I use `psql` however since I deleted (and tried to reinstall) I can't get psql working. (Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client- package.)

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get purge postgresql; sudo apt-get autoremove --purge; sudo apt-get install postgresql` work?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex: No it does not fix the problem (same error)